# FreeBSD memory usage shell script

Tags: freebsd

In FreeBSD, how to find the current memory usage (wired, inactive, cache, etc) in a shell script?

This must be for a regular /bin/sh script, not bash, zsh, etc...

Comment: Have you checked `ps` and `top`? I think both are available on BSD. Not sure about `free`, does that exist on BSDs?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need it :

```
root@firewall:/usr/ports/misc/gnu-watch # uname -a

FreeBSD firewall 10.1-STABLE FreeBSD 10.1-STABLE #0 r279885: Thu Mar 12 01:04:57 CET 2015     root@firewall:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/PF  i386
root@firewall:/usr/ports/misc/gnu-watch # vmstat 
 procs      memory      page                    disks     faults         cpu
 r b w     avm    fre   flt  re  pi  po    fr  sr ad0 pa0   in   sy   cs us sy id
 1 0 0    304M   512M   229   1   1   0   244   5   0   0   47 1001  357  1  2 97
root@firewall:/usr/ports/misc/gnu-watch #
```

vmstat has set of options for command line that you can use in your script.